# Uncompressing cite references locally (with square brackets)

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am in a similar situation as described in this question: [uncompressing cite references locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346891/uncompress-cite-references-locally), but I have a slight complication. I think it is preferable to start a new question instead of leaving a comment on the original one. So here goes:

### Problem

I need to uncompress a cited reference locally (*just this one occasion*), such that instead of `...needs citation [1-5]`, I have something like `...needs citation [1,2-5]`. Notice that ref. 1 is now separated from the main 'group' of references. See the MWE below.

### MWE and attempt

Consider the following MWE (slightly modified from the one in the above link, and one of the solution from that link is applied below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref} % I am using these packages as well
\usepackage{filecontents}

% References
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
    @article{testref1,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref2,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref3,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref4,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref5,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter % Cite references to be in square brackets, superscript
\renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{\textsuperscript{[#1]}} 
\makeatother


% The accepted solution from the original question - Credit to Steven B. Segletes
% \newcommand\mcite[1]{\expandafter\mcitehelp\noexpand#1&\relax} % (Old)
\newcommand\mcite[1]{\mcitehelp#1&\relax}  % (Updated Code)    
\def\mcitehelp#1&#2\relax{\cite{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else$^,$\mcitehelp#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}
    This is some text that requires citation
    \mcite{testref1&testref2, testref3, testref4, testref5}. 

    But this is unsatisfactory because I'd prefer it to look like:

    This is some text that requires citation \textsuperscript{[1,\,2--5]}.

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

A quick look at the output:
[image]

I left the `\hyperref` and `\cleveref` packages in the MWE because hopefully your answer will not interfere with my use of these packages.

I am aware that `\cite` has the option `\uncompress` but that is unsatisfactory because:

- That applies throughout the document. I only need this once.
- It lists all the references singularly `([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])`, which I don't want. I only want *one* reference to be isolated from the group. The rest should stay grouped.

### Question

So I guess my question is, can I get some help with modifying the code so that I can achieve the desired output? I'm still rather new to programming with LaTeX. Thank you!

**TL;DR:**
I want an uncompressed cited reference, just like how the `cleveref` package allows with `\cref{label1, ,label2,label3,label4}` for normal labels, which will give me an output like the one in the picture (bottom one).

Comment: FYI, unrelated to this question, I edited my answer on the cited question... `\newcommand\mcite[1]{\mcitehelp#1&\relax}` is now defined more simply.

Comment: Updated for the benefit of others in the future. Must've missed it -thanks! By any chance, are you able to come up with something similar in my particular case? Not that the current answer by Ulrike Fischer is not satisfactory tho :x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed hyperref for the screenshot, but it works with it too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref} % I am using these packages as well
\usepackage{filecontents}

% References
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
    @article{testref1,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref2,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref3,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref4,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref5,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter % Cite references to be in square brackets, superscript
\renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    This is some text that requires citation%
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter    
    \renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{#1}%    
    \textsuperscript{[\cite{testref1},\,\cite{testref2, testref3, testref4, testref5}]}.
    \endgroup

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do believe it should be `\makeatother` at the end. But it works great as an ad-hoc solution. Thanks!

Comment: There should be nothing at the end (the group ends the \makeatletter anyway).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you switch from using the `cite` citation management package to using the `natbib` citation management package. The `natbib` package should be loaded with the options `super`, `square`, `comma`, and `sort&compress`.

This permits setting up a new dedicated citation macro -- called `\mcitex` in the code below -- that takes two arguments: bib entries before and after a separating comma. The entries in each of the arguments will be sorted and compressed as usual.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
@article{testref1,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=1, year=2016}
@article{testref2,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=2, year=2017}
@article{testref3,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=3, year=2018}
@article{testref4,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=4, year=2019}
@article{testref5,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=5, year=2020}
@article{testref6,
   title = {Test title}, journal = {Test Journal},
   author = {Test authors and others}, volume=6, year=2021}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,square,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\newcommand\mcitex[2]{\textsuperscript{[}\citealp{#1}%
    \textsuperscript{,}\citealp{#2}\textsuperscript{]}}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % just for this example
\begin{document}

text\cite{testref1,testref2, testref3, testref4, testref5}

text%
\mcitex{testref1}{testref2, testref3, testref4, testref5}%
\mcitex{testref1, testref2}{testref3, testref4, testref5}%
\mcitex{testref1, testref2, testref3}{testref4, testref5, testref6}

\bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, using my prior answer, with changes for your current situation, I did two things:

1. I did not add brackets to the modified `\@cite` macro, but instead did this: `\renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}`; and
2. I added the brackets to the `\mcite` macro directly, as in `\newcommand\mcite[1]{$^[$\mcitehelp#1&\relax$^]$}`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref} % I am using these packages as well
\usepackage{filecontents}
% References
\begin{filecontents}{samplebib.bib}
    @article{testref1,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref2,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref3,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref4,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
    @article{testref5,
        title = {Test title},
        journal = {Test Journal},
        author = {Test authors and others},
        volume = {1},
        year = {2016}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter % Cite references to be in square brackets, superscript
\renewcommand{\@cite}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}} 
\makeatother


% The accepted solution from the original question - Credit to Steven B. Segletes
% \newcommand\mcite[1]{\expandafter\mcitehelp\noexpand#1&\relax} % (Old)
\newcommand\mcite[1]{$^[$\mcitehelp#1&\relax$^]$}  % (Updated Code)    
\def\mcitehelp#1&#2\relax{\cite{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else$^,$\mcitehelp#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}
    This is some text that requires citation
    \mcite{testref1&testref2, testref3, testref4, testref5}. 

    But this is unsatisfactory because I'd prefer it to look like:

    This is some text that requires citation \textsuperscript{[1,\,2--5]}.

    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{samplebib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, it seems so obvious when you do it. +1

Comment: edit: Oh but it does mean that all my other references lose their square brackets.. hmm.

Comment: @Troy Unless you use `\mcite` exclusively, yes.

Comment: @Troy One *could* redefine `\cite` to point to `\mcite`: `\let\svcite\cite
\def\mcitehelp#1&#2\relax{\svcite{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else‌​$^,$\mcitehelp#2\relax\fi}
\let\cite\mcite`